# delay chef until a resource has completed its task

Tags: mysql, docker, chef-infra, devops

I have a chef recipe that brings up a mysql docker container, and then, if some logic passes, connects to it to load some database entries.

The problem is, that it always fails it first run, because it goes on to the resource that is in charge of restoring data, before the mysql container is up and ready to accept connections.

Here is the part of the recipe that brings of the container:

```
docker_container 'imhere-mysql' do
  hostname mysqlHost
  repo 'lutraman/imhere'
  tag 'mysql'
  env ["MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=#{mysql_password}"]
  volumes [ '/var/imhere/mysql:/var/lib/mysql' ]
  action :run
end
```

and here is the part that does restoration:

```
remote_file "#{parent_data_dir}/#{db_restore_filename}" do
  source "#{db_restore_url}/#{db_restore_filename}"
  notifies :run, 'execute[mysql_load_dump]'
end

execute "mysql_load_dump" do
  command "#{scripts_dir}/mysql_restore_dump.sh"
  environment(
    'MYSQL_HOSTNAME' => mysqlHost,
    'PARENT_DATA_DIR' => parent_data_dir,
    'DB_RESTORE_FILENAME' => db_restore_filename,
    'MYSQL_PASSWORD' => mysql_password,
    'RETRIES' => "10"
  )
  action :nothing
end
```

This is less relevant, but just for completeness, here is what the script eventually executes:

```
MYSQL_IP_ADDRESS=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $MYSQL_HOSTNAME)

gunzip -c $PARENT_DATA_DIR/$DB_RESTORE_FILENAME | \
mysql -h $MYSQL_IP_ADDRESS -D imhere -u root -p"$MYSQL_PASSWORD"
```

As you can see, I sort of hacked the process so it will do several retries, but that will just introduce a race condition. How can I tell chef to block on the `docker_container` resource until the container is fully ready?

Answer (score 2):

The resource has completed, the issue is that `docker run` itself is not a blocking process. You'll probably want to use a `ruby_block` resource and some Ruby code to sleep until the container actually starts and the server process is accepting connections.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the resource has completed has coderanger said.

Have you tried to notify the dump action from both resources? :

```
docker_container 'imhere-mysql' do
  hostname mysqlHost
  repo 'lutraman/imhere'
  tag 'mysql'
  env ["MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=#{mysql_password}"]
  volumes [ '/var/imhere/mysql:/var/lib/mysql' ]
  notifies :run, 'execute[mysql_load_dump]', :delayed
  action :run
end

remote_file "#{parent_data_dir}/#{db_restore_filename}" do
  source "#{db_restore_url}/#{db_restore_filename}"
  notifies :run, 'execute[mysql_load_dump]', :delayed
end

execute "mysql_load_dump" do
  command "#{scripts_dir}/mysql_restore_dump.sh"
  environment(
    'MYSQL_HOSTNAME' => mysqlHost,
    'PARENT_DATA_DIR' => parent_data_dir,
    'DB_RESTORE_FILENAME' => db_restore_filename,
    'MYSQL_PASSWORD' => mysql_password,
    'RETRIES' => "10"
  )
  action :nothing
end
```